# Button Animation Swift like Cookie Clicker

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, animation, swift3

So lets say I have a Button and a Label and every time I press the Button it shows how many times I've pressed the Label and a +1 pups up on the button in a random position just like in cookie clicker...how would I do that I know how to get the Label to show how many times I've pressed the Button but I have no idea how to show the +1 animation over the Button...?

Answer (score 1):

Create another label over the button that is hidden, and have the label shown when the button is pressed. With the label you can assign a fadein or fadeout animation with a selected timer for duration. I gave you sample code for positioning the label you can find how to do the animation by googling it.

```
label.zposition = 2
```